# Facebook Feed - JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create a user's feed on my page using Facebook JS SDK but I am having issues accessing the values of nested objects.

This is my code:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', function(response) {
        alert(response.data);
    });
```

The alert here will return `[object Object]`

The data object is this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "Some message", 
      "id": "some ID", 
      "created_time": "2014-01-05T22:46:10+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "Link", 
    "next": "Link"
  }
}
```

I need to access the `message` part of the object but I don't  know how.

Answer (score 0):

Simply access the properties directly

```
FB.api('/me/feed', function(response) {
  alert(response.data.message);
});
```

Comment: @Geo that is counter to what you stated - the object you provided clearly had a 'message' property, which you would access using `.message` or `['message']`.

Comment: Ah, there's probably two layers of 'data'. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Geo Then the premise of your question is not accurate. If your response contains the structure you provided, these would work.
Test this by adding a `debugger;` breakpoint to your code, and manually inspect the response object.

Comment: I got the structure from Facebook explorer. Another structure that I had to work before it had similar body `{"name": "Geo", "id": "some ID"}` and you could access the properties by calling them directly `alert(response.name)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use JSON after all

```
FB.api('/me/feed',{limit:10}, function(response){   
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(response.data,["picture"]);
    alert(jsonText);    
  });
```

This will return an array with all the values of 'picture'

This is the example output

```
[{"picture":"https://fbcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net"},
 {"picture":"https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net"},
 {"picture":"https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net"},{},
 {"picture":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like`data` is an array with a single element, so to get `message`, you will want to use `response.data[0].message`